# Sharepoint online User profile properties sync with external LOB system

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online, bcs, sharepoint-userprofile

We are doing planning work to migrate our SharePoint 2010 on prem to SharePoint online. In the current environment , we have setup few custom user profile properties that get synced up with SQL table via BCS (Synchronization connections is consuming the external content type). Now, what should be our approach to implement the same scenario for SharePoint online?. One of the possible solution we found is to created the custom user profile properties and update the values of these properties via custom code using CSOM model or  JSON. But is it the recommended approach? I read that SharePoint online user profile can only sync up with  Active directory (via Dir sync or  Azure AD connect) and not with other external sources OOB. Is this understanding correct?

If anyone has already dealt with such scenario, Please provide guidance. Thanks!